# Can i upload a rssfeed file in SharePoint and use it in my script or rss reader webpart?

Tags: web-part, rss

Is it possible to load a rssfeed file e.g events.rss into a SharePoint document library and then use script or RSS Reader webpart to view it on a page.
When i tried it via using a sharepoint direct url.
The file just keeps downloading.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using?

Comment: Thanks Pradip for the response. Its SharePoint Online

Comment: Could you provide more details about your implementation of adding the RSS feed file to the RSS Reader web part? I would like to understand how you configured it because in my experience, when I attempted to use the RSS Reader web part with a custom RSS feed from a SharePoint library file, it worked as expected.

Comment: This is interesting that it worked.
There is no RSSWebpart in Comm site so i used the one in Teams site.
I created a document library and uploaded a RSS file with .rss extension.
Then i used the url of the file i uploaded in  the RSSwebpart. 
But it didn't work. Can you brief in detail what you did?

Comment: Hi Pradip, I have test it one more time and no luck. I'm getting error
{"status":"error","message":"Feed could not be parsed, probably not a valid RSS feed format."}

Comment: Has any ones or anyone in MS tried this? Is this feasible? 
Any help would be appreciated.